# How to connect mongodb Replicaset in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I have tried this:

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:4000,localhost:4001/bookstore?replicaSet=myapp';


mongoClient.connect(url,(err,db)=>{
    if(err){
        return;
    }
    console.log('connected to the database');
})
```

But how to export the database object(db)?  The db object can be get only in the callback.  Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: Why dont you put it to a module variable and export ?

Comment: @SercanOzdemir like what?

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/mongoclient/mongoclient/blob/master/server/imports/mongodb/methods_common.js#L118

Comment: I can't understand. so How to export it@SercanOzdemir